# VS 2022 Community edition Tabs are overlapsed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So been on this VS 2022 error, that can't get my head around...
From one day to another, my tabs on VS became like the following print screen i shared:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKd2n.png)

As you can see, looks like there is a "curtain" on top of the open file, which is really annoying...
As anybody had this issue?

I already tried unninstalling & installing VS.

Thanks in Advance!